# Qual o nome dessa barra ? [HTML]

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, alguém sabe como se chama esse tipo de barra (barra vermelha na página abaixo), ou o nome do efeito aplicado nela ?

http://arrobba.inf.br/produtos_nfe.htm

Comment: Essa barra foi feita com <table>

Answer (score 2):

Essa barra foi feita com uma `<table>`. Na verdade se vc der um `Ctrl+U` nessa página vc vai ver que ela foi toda feita com tabela, o que é uma técnica muito ultrapassada para montar layouts e nada responsiva!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aqui está o código da barra:**

```css
.produtos-relacao {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #EC3237;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #6A6F75;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="produtos-relacao">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"><a href="produtos_lojas.htm">@Lojas</a></td>
            <td width="20%"><a href="produtos_hotel.htm">@Hotel</a></td>
            <td width="20%"><a href="produtos_nfe.htm">@NFe</a></td>
            <td width="20%"><a href="produtos_sped.htm">@SPED</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**DICA:**

Não use tabela para fazer layouts, tabelas são para dados tabulares. Para fazer layouts use tags semânticas como `main`, `nav`, `section` etc...

Comece estudando para esse links, eles vão te ajudar a entender melhor os fundamentos! https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout e aqui tb https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction Depois de estuda-los vc pode procurar outros frameworks de Design Sistems tipo Bootstrap e Materialize por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado!